# Python overriden methods called from superclass

Tags: python, inheritance, name-mangling

There are lot of information about mangling and it's usage, however I am struggling to understand the following piece of code:

```
class Parent:

    NAME = 'PARENT'

    def __init__(self):
      self.print_me()

    def print_me(self):
      print(f"Parent class {self.NAME}")


class Child(Parent):

    NAME = 'CHILD'

    def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()

    def print_me(self):
      print(f"Child class {self.NAME}")


c = Child()
```

Can someone please explain how the overriden method (print_me) is called from the parent class init and does not print Parent class PARENT?
If I use mangling both for `NAME` and `print_me` the method is not overriden and thus it's called from the parent which is expected.

Comment: What do you think overriding means?

Comment: Nothing here is called in the context of `Parent`. Everything is in the context of `Child`.

Answer (score 0):

Here the object(c) is child class object
In child class the constructor calls the parent class and the parent class constructor calls the print_me method
Here you called the child object so it will execute the child method. If the print_me method is not available in child then it will execute parent method

Answer (score 0):

If you needed it to print the parent function, you should instead create the parent object.

```
c = Parent()
```